# How to manage.one big column into multiple rows in html by python code?

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I have written CSV file in HTML but the problem I am facing is that it has only one big column and I want to manage it in rows So that I don't have to scroll the page. Instead of managing it in HTML manually by giving rows  to it, how could I write it in python with some lines of code and manage it in rows?

```
import csv

html_about = ''
names = []
with open('filo.csv') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(data_file)
    for line in csv_data:
    names.append(f'{line[0]}')

html_output = '\n<ul>'
for name in names:
    html_output += f'\n\t<ul>{name}</ul>'
html_output += '\n</ul>'
print(html_output)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filo.csv')
with open('table.html', 'w') as html_file:
    df.to_html(html_file,index=False)
```

Comment: is there anyone to answer?